# What is wrong with my cocktail sort code?

Tags: java, sorting, methods

I managed to translate the pseudocode of the cocktail sort method but when I run it I get a runtime error displaying this:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Sorting.cocktailSort(Sorting.java:119)
    at Sorting.plotCocktailSortTest(Sorting.java:213)
    at Sorting.main(Sorting.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Here is my code for this sorting method:

```
public static int cocktailSort(String[] numbers) {
    String [] inputCocktail = new String [numbers.length];
    for(int a = 0; a < numbers.length-2; a++) { 
        inputCocktail[a] = numbers [a]; 
    }      
    int left = 0;
    int right = numbers.length;
    boolean swapped =true; 
    String temp = "";
    int counter = 0;
    while (left < right && swapped) {
        swapped =false;
        for  (int mid = 0; mid < numbers.length; mid++) {
            if ((inputCocktail[mid].compareTo(inputCocktail[mid+1]))>0)
            { temp = inputCocktail[mid];
                inputCocktail[mid] = inputCocktail[mid+1];
                inputCocktail[mid+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }  
        }    
        right--;
        if (swapped){
            swapped = false;
            for(int mid = numbers.length-2; mid>0; mid--)
                if ((inputCocktail[mid].compareTo(inputCocktail[mid-1]))<0)
                { temp = inputCocktail[mid];
                    inputCocktail[mid]= inputCocktail[mid-1];
                    inputCocktail[mid-1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
        }    
    }      
    left++;
    counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

I cant find my error no matter how many times I look through my code. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
First method that compares strings:

```
public static int compare(String a, String b)
       { 
  int compared = 0;
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    //program assumes strings are equal

    for (int i = 0; i<a.length() && i<a.length(); i++){
        //for() loop goes on until the largest string
         int c = a.charAt(i);
        int d = b.charAt(i);
        //convert char into int for comparison just in case
        if(c < d){
            compared = -1;
             break;
            //breaks at the first occurence of non equal characters
        }
        else if(c > d){
            compared = 1;
            break;
            //same as above
        }
    }

     return compared;
  }
```

Edit #2:

```
  public static void plotCocktailSortTest(int N_MAX) {
    int[] cocktail_sort_results = new int[N_MAX];

// test sorting for arrays from size 1 to N_MAX
    // MAKE SURE THAT YOUR METHOD IS ACTUALLY SORTING THE TEST ARRAY!!!!!!
    for (int i = 1; i < N_MAX; i++) {
      String[] test_array = ArrayUtilities.getRandomNamesArray(i);
      cocktail_sort_results[i] = cocktailSort(test_array);
    }
    // create a plot window
    PlotWindow pw = new PlotWindow("Cocktail Sort!");
    // add a plot to the window using our results array
    pw.addPlot("CocktailSort", cocktail_sort_results);
  }
```

Comment: I suggest you look for the shortest data set which triggers this bug and step through the code in your debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks wrong

```
for  (int mid = 0; mid < numbers.length; mid++) {
       if ((inputCocktail[mid].compareTo(inputCocktail[mid+1]))>0)
```

as previously you are only filling up `inputCocktail` with elements up to `numbers.length - 2`

based upon your newly posted code

```
for (int i = 1; i < N_MAX; i++) {
      String[] test_array = ArrayUtilities.getRandomNamesArray(i);
```

I have no idea what `ArrayUtilities` is, but maybe `getRandomNamesArray(1)` would return an array of size `1`

In your later code, you are trying to access array based upon `size - 2` and `size + 1` which will obviously failed.

Comment: I changed it to     numbers.length - 2 but is still gives me the same error.

Comment: What?? Please show how you are calling this code and what parameters you are using.

Comment: I dont get what you want  me to show... sorry im new to java. I could add my entire code if you want.

Comment: This method `public static int cocktailSort(String[] numbers) {` is being called from somewhere isnt it.  SHOW ME.

Comment: NO, if you look at your error stacktrace you will see  at `Sorting.cocktailSort(Sorting.java:119)
    at Sorting.plotCocktailSortTest(Sorting.java:213)
    at Sorting.main(Sorting.java:19)`  This means that this method is being called from `plotCocktailSortTes` at line 213.  Quick, help me to help you

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Learn to debug, it is essential for a competent  programmer to know how to debug.